# Request mapping issue with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, request-mapping

So I'm following a guide I found to scoping Spring Beans: http://richardchesterwood.blogspot.com/2011/03/using-sessions-in-spring-mvc-including.html

I'm using the 3rd option, which means my components are scoped at session and my controllers are scoped at request, and the components are autowired into the controllers (so they only have one instance per session).

But when I do this I get the eclipse error:

> Cannot map handler 'somethingsController' to URL path
>   [/SomethingsPage]: There is already handler
>   'scopedTarget.somethingsController' mapped.

In my controller I have a method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "SomethingsPage")
    public ModelAndView changeTheSomething(HttpServletRequest request) {
        [...]
    }
```

And if I comment out that method everything works great. (Except that method.) So for some reason using requestmapping inside that controller like that causes something to break. Is there some way I can change my request mapping to make it all work?

So I'm thinking the issue has something to do with the controller being scanned twice by my spring xml and that causing the @Requestmapping to be mapped a second time which throws the error. Is there something wrong with how my xml file is set up considering how I'm using my classes' annotations in terms of scoping and autowiring?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Use @Component annotations for bean definitions -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="controllers, daos, map, models, session, testControllers"  scoped-proxy="targetClass" />
    <!-- added this because I think it makes annotations work? -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Use @Controller annotations for MVC controller definitions -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    [... bunch of other stuff that shouldn't be relevant]
```

Comment: do you have also @RequestMapping on your controller-class?

Comment: I've tried it both ways, but it gives the same error either way.

Comment: Try adding `method=RequestMethod.GET` or `method=RequestMethod.POST` or whatever request method you need along with the `@RequestMapping()` annotation.

Comment: Still giving me the same error.

Comment: try @RequestMapping(value = "/somethingspage")

Comment: That also doesn't change the error. I think for some reason in my controller class is being scanned twice in my spring xml configuration, and when that happens it tries to map twice to @RequestMapping(value = "somethingspage). Here, I'll post my spring xml file into the question as well.

Comment: The exception message indicates that the controller `scopedTarget.somethingsController` has already been mapped with this URL. Did you have such a controller mapped with that URL?

Comment: I only have one mapping for that controller, and only one mapping for that request mapping value. I do put that bean into my jsp file for that page though: <jsp:useBean id="something" class="controllers.somethingsController"
 scope="request" />

Comment: i think this is youtr problem:  scoped-proxy="targetClass"  try to remove this, or move your controllers package to other <context:component-scan /> without proxy

Comment: The thing builds like that! It's a miracle! Of course when I try to use the method, I still get another error "HTTP ERROR: 500

No Scope registered for scope 'Request'"
but you've solved my major issue! You're amazing! (I've spent hours upon hours trying to fix this.)